# DB2 9.7 task center do not work in SUSE 11 sp4 - DBA1176N

Tags: linux, suse, db2

I've install DB2 9.7 enterprise edition on suse 11 sp4, the problem is that when i want to see "task center" it show's bellow error:

> DBA1176N  The Control Center failed to automatically catalog the 
>   Tools Catalog Database "" for system "BM-BACKUP42".
>
> Explanation:
>
> Possible explanations are: 
>   *  The database is specified incorrectly at the DB2 Administration    Server for system "".
>   *  The database manager that contains the database is not configured for    TCP/IP communication.
>
> User response:
>
> Possible solutions include: 
>   *  Verify that the DB2 Administration Server configuration parameters    are correctly specified.
>   *  Verify that the database manager is configured for TCP/IP    communications.
>
> If the problem persists, contact IBM Support.

problem isn't exist on suse 11 sp3
does anyone faced with same problem?
any help will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

DB2 9.7 is long out of support, and also the Control Center and its associated components were deprecated in Version 9.7 and were removed from future releases.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/c0021917.html

Maybe you need to consider using a supported version.

Alternatively,

> Database, database alias and instance name lengths must be less than or equal to 8 bytes.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0007246.html

and your error message says you are trying to catalog the name `BM-BACKUP42` which is 11 bytes long in UTF-8 or ASCII

Comment: yes,i know
but i have to use db2 9.7

Comment: OK, so the issue might be the length of your database alias. You are using "BM-BACKUP42" but database names have to be 8 characters or less in DB2.

Comment: thank you for response, "BM-BACKUP42" is my host name!